# node.js cannot read json from mongoexport

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I've exported a collection from mongo using the following command:

```
mongoexport -d <database-name> -c <collection-name> -o foo.json
```

Export worked fine and produced `foo.json` which looked like this:

```
{
  "_id" : { "$oid" : "76safuysadf76tsaydgf" },
  "name" : "John",
  "number" : 3
}
{
  "_id" : { "$oid" : "dfsafuysaasdf7tsayd6" },
  "name" : "Fred",
  "number" : 4
}
{
  "_id" : { "$oid" : "876sfuyg7rfasff4ffff" },
  "name" : "Paul",
  "number" : 1
}
```

Now I want to read this json file with node.js, edit the data and save back to the file (or a new file). For example I want to remove the `number` field from each user.

I'm having trouble reading the file with node. I tried this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./foo.json"));
console.log(obj);
```

But I get the following error:

```
uncaughtException: Unexpected token {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: try removing `JSON.parse`, as it looks more like a javascript object

Comment: @adeneo I then this in the console: `<Buffer 7b 20 22 5f 69 64 22 20 3a 20...`

Comment: The output is not JSON Array, it just the verbose, try forming a valid JSON arrary and then use JSON.parse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**
From the `mongoexport` docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Use the `--jsonArray` option to get output in a JSON array, as I described in my original answer.

**Original Answer**

It looks like you are trying to parse a JSON array, instead of one object. Try adding `[]` and commas to the output from mongoexport so it looks like this:

```
[{
   "_id" : { "$oid" : "76safuysadf76tsaydgf" },
   "name" : "John",
   "number" : 3
},
{
   "_id" : { "$oid" : "dfsafuysaasdf7tsayd6" },
   "name" : "Fred",
   "number" : 4
},
{
   "_id" : { "$oid" : "876sfuyg7rfasff4ffff" },
   "name" : "Paul",
   "number" : 1
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the formatting of the objects - commas and enclosing square brackets as you say.